# Why is "hello" printed twice in this Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I decided to experiment with defining methods inside methods in Ruby and wrote this:

```
def foo
  def bar
    puts "hello"
  end
  bar
end
```

This defined, I ran `foo` and "hello" was printed as I expected. However I then tried `foo.bar` - which printed out "hello" twice. Why?

Comment: I'm not trying to fix the script, just understand it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo.bar` equals `foo().bar()` so you call first `foo` which contains `bar` so it is executed once here, then `bar` is executed one more time. At the end `bar` is called twice.

```
def foo
  puts 'foo called'
  def bar
    puts 'bar called'
    puts "hello"
  end
  bar
end
foo.bar
#=> foo called
#=> bar called
#=> hello
#=> bar called
#=> hello
```

What I don't understand is this means the result of `foo` which is `nil` can call `bar`.

```
>> nil.bar
#=> hello
```

How is that possible ?

**Edit**: As explained in some answers, nested method are included in the class scope so weither bar is declared inside or outside foo does not make any difference.

Also Matz [said](http://www.rubyist.net/~matz/20101113.html) that it may change from Ruby2.0

here is the example he wrote:

```
class Foo
  def foo
    def bar
      #omited
    end
    bar # can be called
  end

  def quux
    bar # cannot be called
  end
end
```

**edit-Ruby2.0**: It finally did not get implemented. So it remains the same.

Comment: But shouldn't `foo.bar` call `bar` on the return value of `foo`, which is the return value of `bar`, which is the return value of `puts`, which *isn't* `foo`?

Comment: What I mean is, shouldn't you expect a `NoMethodError`?

Comment: I just edited my answer as I thought about the same. The result of puts is nil so... I don't have any idea.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.2 `bar` and `foo` are private methods for `nil` so it will cause error.

Comment: @Hauleth I am using 1.8.7 but even, how which the OP code can bar be called from nil ?

Comment: Apparently it's monkey-patching `NilClass` to contain the method `bar`. `foo` calls `bar` which returns the monkey-patched nil. I'm just not sure why `NilClass` is monkey patched.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is wrong as bar is not called on foo twice, but once on foo and once on nil. The danger of not namespacing things!

Comment: It's money patching Object I think, whatever class the irb console is running as. NilClass is a subclass. (Please ignore last comment, on train and wrote it before I saw updates )

Comment: Having said all that, I'm still interested on why bar is defined on object when it is defined *inside* foo?

Comment: @Russell Ruby doesn't have nested methods. foo() and bar() are in the same scope. So you will get the same behavior if you define foo and bar separately.

Comment: Thanks Tatu, that explains it!

Comment: Matz apparently said that this will change from Ruby2.0. You can see the link here if you speak japanese http://www.rubyist.net/~matz/20101113.html

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, there is a hidden variable that doesn't get much attention. I don't know what it's called, but I call it the current class. This variable is the target of `def`

When you go into `foo`, it doesn't change this variable, you're still in the same class. So when you define another method inside of foo, that method gets defined on the same class as foo was defined on.

In this case, you're defining foo on main, the toplevel object. Main's current class variable is set to object, so any methods you define here will be available inside any object.

Since the last thing you do is return the result of bar, and bar returns nil (b/c puts returns nil), then `foo.bar` is `nil.bar`. And since you defined bar on Object, even nil inherits this method.

The interesting part is that bar is public. Since foo is defined in main, and main sets its scope to private, I would have expected bar to also be private, but I guess that state must lost once you go to a different scope.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to put `class foo`?  It seems that calling foo.bar calls the function foo and then the function bar.  Calling `nil.bar` prints out 'hello' too.

Comment: Aha, you've hit on the answer! I didn't mean to put `class`, I just defined a method in irb, and because I didn't namespace it in a class it was defined on object. So the second call of `bar` was on `nil`. If you update your answer to explain this I'll accept it.

Comment: I saw your comment 17 hours later, other people have provided details and further info, but I hope I helped provide some insight.

Comment: You did, thanks, when you pointed out that nil.bar worked I realised straight away what was going on.